# Simple C# Program - Classes/Objects

Tags: c#

I was given starter code in C# and told to write code that will make it work. This is the starter code that I was given:

```
namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cup coffeeCup = new Cup() { TypeOfCup = TypeOfCup.Coffee };
            coffeeCup.AddItem(new liquid().WithDescription("Coffee"));
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I wrote in attempts to make the starter code function:

```
namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cup coffeeCup = new Cup() { TypeOfCup = TypeOfCup.Coffee };
            coffeeCup.AddItem(new liquid().WithDescription("Coffee"));
        }
    }
    class Cup {
        public string TypeOfCup { get; set;}
        public int numItems;
        public Cup() {
            this.numItems = 0;
        }
        public void AddItem() {
            numItems += 1;
        }
    }
    class liquid {
        public string description;
        public liquid() {

        }
        public void WithDescription(string description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
    }
}
```

I receive 2 errors:

1. The name 'TypeOfCup' does not exist in the current context
2. Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void'

I am a beginner in C# so I apologize if this is a silly problem. Any insight or tips on how to fix these errors/code would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) The `TypeOfCup` property needs to be of type `enum TypeOfCup`. 2) The `AddItem` method needs to take a parameter of type `liquid`. 3) The `WithDescription` method needs to have a return type of `liquid`, likely returning `this`.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Technically `AddItem` could take an `interface` eg IPourable which `liquid` implements. There are more things that you can sensibly add to a cup than liquids.

Comment: @Jonathan Sure! These are just hints aiming at the most basic implementation that would fix the OP's errors. Other things need to be decided, of course. For example, `AddItem` would need to actually do something with the argument passed to it, like adding it to a collection or assigning it to a property, etc. The question doesn't have enough details about the requirements though.

Comment: Depending on whether the model defines a cup item as being of type Liquid, or just an arbitrary item. If a cup can also contain other things (sugar, flour, etc.) then the cup needs to contain a List<ICanGoInCup>> where ICanGoInCup is declared as an interface implemented by all the classes allowed, (Liquid,  Flour, Sugar, etc.), which defines all the properties/behaviors that any object passed to the cup needs to be able to implement within the Cup class.  Then you could AddItem of any of those types.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to implement `TypeOfCup` as enum:

```cs
enum TypeOfCup {
    None,
    Coffee,
    Tea,
    Chocolate
}
```

The enum constants are always accessed through the enum name: `TypeOfCup.Coffee`.

While this is the most idiomatic implementation, you could also implement `TypeOfCup` as constants or static properties:

```cs
static class TypeOfCup
{
    public const int None = 0;
    public const int Coffee = 1;
    public const int Tea = 2;
    public const int Chocolate = 3;
}
```

or

```cs
static class TypeOfCup
{
    public static int None => 0;
    public static int Coffee => 1;
    public static int Tea => 2;
    public static int Chocolate => 3;
}
```

Another problem is

> Error  CS1501  No overload for method 'AddItem' takes 1 arguments

You are supposed to pass it an object of type `liquid`, therefore `AddItem` must have a corresponding parameter. This means that a `Cup` should sensibly contain a collection storing those liquids instead of just a counter. Something like this:

```cs
class Cup
{
    public TypeOfCup TypeOfCup { get; set; }

    public List<liquid> Liquids { get; } = new List<liquid>();

    public void AddItem(liquid liquid)
    {
        Liquids.Add(liquid);
    }
}
```

The error

> Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to '[...].liquid'

comes from the fact that the method `WithDescription` does not return an instance of the liquid. It should be implemented as

```cs
class liquid
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public liquid WithDescription(string description)
    {
        Description = description;
        return this;
    }
}
```

This allows calling `coffeeCup.AddItem(new liquid().WithDescription("Coffee"));` where the liquid that was added a description is passed to `AddItem` after a call to `WithDescription`.

Note that returning `this` is a common practice that allows chaining methods like this:

```
coffeeCup.AddItem(
    new liquid()
        .WithDescription("Coffee")
        .WithTemperature(50)
        .WithQuantity(20.5)
);
```

The same instance of the liquid is passed through this call chain.

According to the usual [C# naming conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md) class name must be in CamelCase. Therefore the liquid class should be named `Liquid`; however, that's an error in the starter code given to you.

Comment: Instead of chaining, assuming Description, Temperature and Quantity are all public read/write properties, it is IMHO much better to initiate the object like this `new liquid { Description = "Coffee", Temperature = 50, Quantity = 20.5 }`. I therefore think it more likely that the exercise intends that Description should be read only.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock,yes, I thought of that; However, the task was just to "make it work". In theory, it is not even necessary to expose this property. The given code is not consistent. For example, `TypeOfCup` is assigned in the initializer. The C# 9.0 `init` keyword could be used here. Without further context, it is difficult to make decisions.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace Sample
{
    enum TypeOfCup
    {
        Coffee,
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cup coffeeCup = new() { TypeOfCup = TypeOfCup.Coffee };
            coffeeCup.AddItem(new liquid().WithDescription("Coffee"));
        }
    }

    class Cup
    {
        public TypeOfCup TypeOfCup { get; set; }
        public List<liquid> Liquids { get; set; } = new List<liquid>();

        public void AddItem(liquid liquid)
        {
            Liquids.Add(liquid);
        }
    }

    class liquid
    {
        public string description = "";

        public liquid()
        {

        }
        public liquid(string description)
        {
            this.description = description;
        }
        public liquid WithDescription(string description)
        {
            this.description = description;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are allowed to change your code in de Main function, then you probably should replace `coffeeCup.AddItem(new liquid().WithDescription("Coffee"))` with `coffeeCup.AddItem(new liquid("Coffee"))`

Comment: For what is clearly a homework question, it is best to give hints as to what is wrong rather than simply providing a full solution, for all sorts of reasons, not least  because many teachers check SO as well!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose each cup has a type and a description.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Cup coffeeCup = new Cup() { TypeOfCup = TypeOfCup.Coffee };
        coffeeCup.AddItem(new liquid().WithDescription("Coffee"));
    }
}

class Cup
{
    public TypeOfCup TypeOfCup { get; set; }
    private liquid Liquid { get; set; }

    public void AddItem(liquid liquid)
    {
        this.Liquid = liquid;
    }
}

class liquid
{
    private string Description { get; set; }

    public liquid WithDescription(string description)
    {
        this.Description = description;
        return this;
    }
}

enum TypeOfCup
{
    Coffee,
    Tea,
}
```